# Issue with integrating new Google Sign-In into my Android App

Tags: android, google-signin, android-googleapiclient

My `SignInActivity` extends `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` as I am using `AccountManager` but in new Google Sign-In, `GoogleApiClient.Builder` require FragmentActivity to enableAutoManage ex:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) 
.enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */) 
.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso) .build();
```

How can I fix this issue?